# Sending POST request to node.js server

Tags: html, node.js, post

I have a .net application which sends the following request to a node js server:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.PostAsync("http://some_url.com", some_string);
```

What I want to do is extract some_string from the post request on my server. 
The post request comes in but I am unsure how to get the string from it. What I do:

```
if (req.method == 'POST') {
var body = '';
        req.on('data,', function (data) {
            body += data;
            console.log(data);
        });
```

But this does not do anything.  I can see the length of my data in the req.headers property but where is the data itself? Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: `req.body` should give u `some_string`

Comment: You need another event handler `req.on('end', function(){ console.log(body); });`